# How to keep javascript responses on the page?

Tags: javascript, chat

I am creating a very basic robot chat widget, and so far I have the code below, and i was wondering how to i keep the responses on the page? Instead of them disappearing after you type something new in the input field? Preferably one under another.

So the output would be some thing like this:
"how are you?"
"Good thanks, yourself?"

```
<script>
function submit() {
    var userMsg = document.getElementById('user').value;
     var userImput = userMsg.toLowerCase();
  switch(userImput){
case 'hello':
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Hello";
break;
case 'how are you?':
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Good thanks, yourself?";
break;
case 'good':
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Great";
break;
case 'how old are you?':
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Im a computer, so I dont age!";
break;
default:
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "sorry, i dont understand.";
}
}
</script>

<p id="userMsg"></p>
<p id="computerMsg"></p>
<input type="text" id="user" />
<button onclick="submit();" href="javascript:;">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatinate your old content, you are overwriting innerHTML and ofcourse the old content disappears.

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('computerMsg').innerHTML = "Hello";
```

Use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('computerMsg');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "Hello";
```

If you want to a new line you can simply use html tags like br:

```
var element = document.getElementById('computerMsg');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "Hello<br />";
```

//////////////////

The following stuff is just an optional hint.

Maybe you should consider to use or get familar with [JQUery](http://jquery.com/).

With JQuery it is alot easier to access elements by ID and to change its value.
You have alot of benefits like great browser compatiblity being taken care about for you in the back ground and a wide set of functions and very easy element selectors and much more.

Every option would be just a simple oneliner here:

For example:

```
$("#computerMsg").append("Hello"); //Add some content

$("#computerMsg").prepend("Hello"); //Add some content at the beginning

$("#computerMsg").html("Hello"); //Overwrite Content

var content = $("#computerMsg").html(); //Read content
```